# wrong output of classifier

Tags: tensorflow.js

I'm new to machine learning and i used an [mnist](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/mnist) demo model to train a cat and dog classifier.But it doesn't seem to work very well.Here are some diagrams of the model：

[image: onEpochEnd]
[image: onBatchEnd]
[image: perClassAccuracy]

[image: info]

It seems that this model always predicts any input as a cat.
This is my code. Please help me.

**index.js:**

```js
import {IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W, MnistData} from './data.js';


import * as ui from './ui.js';


let classNum = 0;
function createConvModel() {

    const model = tf.sequential();
    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
        inputShape: [IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W, 3],
        kernelSize: 5,
        filters: 32,
        activation: 'relu'
    }));

    model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize: 2, strides: 2}));

    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({kernelSize: 5, filters: 32, activation: 'relu'}));

    model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize: 2, strides: 2}));

    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({kernelSize: 5, filters: 64, activation: 'relu'}));

    model.add(tf.layers.flatten({}));

    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 64, activation: 'relu'}));

    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: classNum, activation: 'softmax'}));

    return model;
}


function createDenseModel() {
    const model = tf.sequential();
    model.add(tf.layers.flatten({inputShape: [IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W, 3]}));
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 42, activation: 'relu'}));
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: classNum, activation: 'softmax'}));
    return model;
}

async function train(model, fitCallbacks) {
    ui.logStatus('Training model...');

    const optimizer = 'rmsprop';

    model.compile({
        optimizer,
        loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy',
        metrics: ['accuracy'],
    });

    const batchSize = 64;

    const trainEpochs = ui.getTrainEpochs();

    let trainBatchCount = 0;

    const trainData = data.getTrainData();
    const valData = data.getValData();
    const testData = data.getTestData();


    await model.fit(trainData.xs, trainData.labels, {
        batchSize:batchSize,
        validationData:[valData.xs,valData.labels],
        shuffle:true,
        epochs: trainEpochs,
        callbacks: fitCallbacks
    });
    console.log("complete");
    const classNames = ['cat','dog'];
    const [preds, labels] = doPrediction(model,testData);
    const classAccuracy = await tfvis.metrics.perClassAccuracy(labels, preds);
    const container = { name: 'Accuracy', tab: 'Evaluation' };
    tfvis.show.perClassAccuracy(container, classAccuracy, classNames);

}

function doPrediction(model,testData) {
    const testxs = testData.xs;
    const labels = testData.labels.argMax([-1]);
    const preds = model.predict(testxs).argMax([-1]);

    testxs.dispose();
    return [preds, labels];
}

function createModel() {
    let model;
    const modelType = ui.getModelTypeId();
    if (modelType === 'ConvNet') {
        model = createConvModel();
    } else if (modelType === 'DenseNet') {
        model = createDenseModel();
    } else {
        throw new Error(`Invalid model type: ${modelType}`);
    }
    return model;
}

async function watchTraining(model) {
    const metrics = ['loss', 'val_loss', 'acc', 'val_acc'];
    const container = {
        name: 'charts', tab: 'Training', styles: { height: '1000px' }
    };
    const callbacks = tfvis.show.fitCallbacks(container, metrics);
    return train(model, callbacks);
}

let data;
async function load() {
    tf.disableDeprecationWarnings();
    classNum = await localforage.getItem('classNum');
    tfvis.visor();
    data = new MnistData();
    await data.load();
}


ui.setTrainButtonCallback(async () => {
    ui.logStatus('Loading data...');
    await load();

    ui.logStatus('Creating model...');
    const model = createModel();
    model.summary();

    ui.logStatus('Starting model training...');

    await watchTraining(model);
});
```

**data.js:**

```js
export const IMAGE_H = 64;
export const IMAGE_W = 64;
const IMAGE_SIZE = IMAGE_H * IMAGE_W;
let NUM_CLASSES = 0;
let trainImagesLabels;
let testLabels;
let trainImages ;
let testImages ;
let validateImages;
let validateLabels;
let validateSplit = 0.2;
let modelId;
let classNum;

/**
 * A class that fetches the sprited MNIST dataset and provide data as
 * tf.Tensors.
 */
export class MnistData {
  constructor() {}

    //shuffle
    static shuffleSwap(arr1,arr2) {
        if(arr1.length == 1) return {arr1,arr2};
        let i = arr1.length;
        while(--i > 1) {
            let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
            [arr1[i], arr1[j]] = [arr1[j], arr1[i]];
            [arr2[i], arr2[j]] = [arr2[j], arr2[i]];
        }
        return {arr1,arr2};
    }

  async load() {
    //get data from localforage
    this.trainImages = await localforage.getItem('dataset');
    this.trainImagesLabels = await localforage.getItem('datasetLabel');
    this.modelId = await localforage.getItem('modelId');
    this.classNum = await localforage.getItem('classNum');

      this.trainImages.shift();
      this.trainImagesLabels.shift();

      //construct the validateData
      let status = false;
      let maxVal = Math.floor(this.trainImages.length * 0.2);

      this.validateImages = new Array();
      this.validateLabels = new Array();
    for(let i=0;i<maxVal;i++){
      if(status){
          this.validateImages.push(this.trainImages.pop());
          this.validateLabels.push(this.trainImagesLabels.pop());
          status = false;
      }else{
          this.validateImages.push(this.trainImages.shift());
          this.validateLabels.push(this.trainImagesLabels.shift());
          status = true;
      }
    }
    //construct the testData
      this.testImages = new Array();
      this.testLabels = new Array();
      for(let i=0;i<maxVal;i++){
          if(status){
              this.testImages.push(this.trainImages.pop());
              this.testLabels.push(this.trainImagesLabels.pop());
              status = false;
          }else{
              this.testImages.push(this.trainImages.shift());
              this.testLabels.push(this.trainImagesLabels.shift());
              status = true;
          }
      }
    //shuffle
      let val = MnistData.shuffleSwap(this.validateImages,this.validateLabels);
      this.validateImages = val.arr1;
      this.validateLabels = val.arr2;
      let train = MnistData.shuffleSwap(this.trainImages,this.trainImagesLabels);
      this.trainImages = train.arr1;
      this.trainImagesLabels = train.arr2;
  }



  getTrainData() {
    const xs = tf.tensor4d(this.trainImages);
    const labels = tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d(this.trainImagesLabels,'int32'),this.classNum);
    return {xs, labels};
  }



    getValData() {
        const xs = tf.tensor4d(this.validateImages);
        const labels = tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d(this.validateLabels,'int32'),this.classNum);
        return {xs, labels};
    }

    getTestData() {
        const xs = tf.tensor4d(this.testImages);
        const labels = tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d(this.testLabels,'int32'),this.classNum);
        return {xs, labels};
    }
}
```

I added some pictures at the beginning.

```js
  
  //getclassNum
  function getClassNum(files) {
        let classArr = new Array();
        let dirArr = new Array();
        let imageNum = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].type.split('/')[0] == 'image' && files[i].type.split('/')[1] == 'jpeg') {
                dirArr = files[i].webkitRelativePath.split('/');
                let currentClassIndex = dirArr.length - 2;
                let isExist = false;
                if (currentClassIndex <= 0)
                    isExist = true;
                else {
                    imageNum++;
                }
                if (classArr == null) {
                    classArr.push(dirArr[currentClassIndex]);
                }
                for (let j = 0; j < classArr.length; j++) {
                    if (classArr[j] == dirArr[currentClassIndex]) {
                        isExist = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!isExist) {
                    classArr.push(dirArr[currentClassIndex]);
                }
            }
        }
        let classNum = classArr.length;
        return {classNum, imageNum, classArr};
    }
  //get nested array
  function getDataset(files, classArr,imgNum) {
        let trainLabelArr = new Array();
        let trainDataArr = new Array();
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].type.split('/')[0] == 'image'&& files[i].type.split('/')[1] == 'jpeg') {
                let dirArr = files[i].webkitRelativePath.split('/');
                let currentClassIndex = dirArr.length - 2;
                if (currentClassIndex >= 0) {
                    for(let j=0;j<classArr.length;j++){
                        if(dirArr[currentClassIndex]==classArr[j]){
                            let reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
                            reader.onload = function () {
                                document.getElementById('image').setAttribute( 'src', reader.result);
                                let tensor= tf.browser.fromPixels(document.getElementById('image'));
                                let nest =  tensor.arraySync();

                                trainDataArr.push(nest);
                                trainLabelArr.push(j);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return{trainDataArr,trainLabelArr,trainDataLength}
    }
  //getfiles
  async function fileChange(that) {
        let files = that.files;
        let container = getClassNum(files);
          
        let data = getDataset(files, container.classArr,container.imageNum);
        let trainDataArr = data.trainDataArr;
        let trainLabelArr = data.trainLabelArr;

        setTimeout(function () {
  
            localforage.setItem('dataset',trainDataArr,function (err,result) {
                 
            });
             localforage.setItem('datasetLabel',trainLabelArr,function (err,result) {

            });
             localforage.setItem('modelId',modelId,function (err,result) {

            });
             localforage.setItem('classNum',container.classNum,function (err,result) {

            });
        },container.imageNum * 10);

        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my question. After a day of testing, I found that this model needs a lot of data. Each category requires at least 1,000 images. If there is not enough training data, the model can only output one result. Moreover, this model performs very well in recognizing objects with fewer characters such as letters and signs, and not very well in recognizing animals or natural environments.